# ASP.NET identity impersonate failing domain admin

Tags: asp.net, identity, impersonation, folder-permissions

I have asp.net web site and trying to access shared folders in servers when i use my username and password on identity impersonate, it is working fine and letting me to check logged in users permission to folder however if i try service account which is domain admin also then gives "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." on DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl(folder);

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="DomainUser" password="Password"/>
```

When i login to that service account it has full control access to all those folders.

```
    public string GetFolderPermissions(string folder, string user) {
        string permissionShort = string.Empty;

        string executingUser = user;
        NTAccount acc = new NTAccount(executingUser);
        SecurityIdentifier secId = acc.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)) as SecurityIdentifier;
        DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl(folder);


        AuthorizationRuleCollection authRules = dirSec.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

        foreach(FileSystemAccessRule ar in authRules) {
            if(secId.CompareTo(ar.IdentityReference as SecurityIdentifier) == 0) {
                var fileSystemRights = ar.FileSystemRights;

                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.FullControl) == FileSystemRights.FullControl) ? "F" : "-";
                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Write) == FileSystemRights.Write) ? "W" : "-";
                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Read) == FileSystemRights.Read) ? "R" : "-";
                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute) == FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute) ? "A" : "-";
                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ListDirectory) == FileSystemRights.ListDirectory) ? "L" : "-";
                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Modify) == FileSystemRights.Modify) ? "M" : "-";
                permissionShort += ((ar.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile) == FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile) ? "E" : "-";
                permissionShort += "\n";

            }

        }
        return permissionShort;
    }
```

I dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not related with service account it was one of the folder that logged in user only has read access only so it cannot check the permission. I did not need to use impersonation since i use service account as application pool default account.